# MySql DB Design -Which is the best of the two- Normalized or Not

Tags: mysql, database

Please see the analysis below and let me know the best db design (InnoDB) out of the two. Requirement- Faster Write and Read for users not having to wait when many concurrent DB connections exists, which are expected to increase exponentially. Disk space advantage is irrelevant if users have to wait.

Assumption – single CPU (just for comparison)

Method 1 (M1) Table1 UserProfile -> UserID, City, State, Country

Method2 (M2)(Normalized) Table2a UserProfile->UserID,LocationsID Table2b Locations-> LocationsID, City, State, Country

Write (Sequence is not in order)

a. Write to Table

M1-Direct Write= t1 M2-(Search Table2b to see record exists=t2+ Insert if no match=t1 Write UserID and LocationsID in Table 2a=t3)
(t1+t2+t3) > t1

b.CPU Interrupts

M1=1,M2=2

c.Disk I/O

M1=1,M2=2

d.Row locks & Releases

M1=1,M2=2

e. Disk space

M1=More, M2=Less(Only advantege in M2)

Read (Assuming record not in Cache)

a. Read from table

M1-Direct read=t4, M2-Join-t5 t5>t4

b. CPU Interrupts

M1=1, M2=2

c.Disk I/O

M1=1,M2=2

I believe, time spent in Method2 can be improved if Table2b is pre-populated or if Country, State, City dropdowns are numerically tagged.
Even if you load balance M1 seems to be an attractive design. Increasing BW may worsen the situation as there will be more concurrent DB connections. Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

> Method2 (M2)(Normalized) Table2a UserProfile->UserID,LocationsID Table2b Locations-> LocationsID, City, State, Country

You have replaced the city, state, and country with an id number. While that might be a good design decision in some cases, it's not always a good design decision. And it has *nothing* to do with normalization. (There's no such thing as "I used an id number" normal form.)

When there's an international standard, it usually makes sense to use it.
See [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). Three-letter codes might make more sense.

```
-- Untested code.
create table countries (
  iso_country_code char(2) not null,
  country_name varchar(35) not null,
  primary key (iso_country_code),
  unique (country_name)
);

create table states (
  state_code char(2) not null,          -- application-dependent, consider ISO 3166-2
  state_abbrev varchar(7) not null,
  state_name varchar(35) not null,
  iso_country_code char(2) not null,
  primary key (state_code, iso_country_code),
  unique (state_abbrev, iso_country_code),
  unique (state_name, iso_country_code),
  foreign key (iso_country_code) references countries (iso_country_code)
);

create table cities (
  city_name varchar(35) not null,
  state_code char(2) not null,
  iso_country_code char(2) not null,
  primary key (city_name, state_code, iso_country_code),
  foreign key (state_code, iso_country_code) 
    references states (state_code, iso_country_code)
);

create table UserProfile (
  UserID integer not null,
  city_name varchar(35) not null,
  state_code char(2) not null,
  iso_country_code char(2) not null,
  primary key (UserID),
  foreign key (city_name, state_code, iso_country_code) 
    references cities (city_name, state_code, iso_country_code)
);
```

Separate tables for countries, states, and cities make it easy to populate combo boxes with SELECT statements. They need no numeric "tags".  All three of those tables are all key; they have no non-prime attributes. I think they're in 5NF.

As a rule of thumb, don't search for a row to see whether it exists, then insert if it doesn't. That requires two round-trips to the database.

Instead, just insert the row, and trap the error you'll get if it's a duplicate. You *have* to trap errors anyway--there are a lot of things that can keep an insert from succeeding besides duplication.